# Showing duplicates in columns of csv files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to read a particular column ("Labels") of any .csv file in a path. Then I want to print each duplicate and the number of times that duplicate appeared.

```
import os
import csv
from collections import Counter

items = []

directory = os.path.join("c:\\","Users\Bob\Desktop\CSVs")
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
       if file.endswith(".csv"):
           with open(file) as csvFile:
               reader = csv.DictReader(file)
               for row in reader:
                   items.append(row["Labels"])
                   print(row)

counted = dict(Counter(items))

print(counted)
```

I get the following error

```
  File "C:/Users/Bob/Desktop/CSVs/Dupe Check.py", line 14, in <module>
    items.append(row["Labels"])
KeyError: 'Labels'
```

The labels column is always the second column of the csv files.

Comment: Try `print(row)` *before* the call to `append()`. That should help you debug.

Comment: Hmm I got OrderedDict([('m', 'a')]).  I'm not sure what to make of that as neither 'm' nor 'a' appear in the csv. After the print I got the same error as before.

Comment: So clearly `Labels` is not in that file. Try opening it up in a text editor and checking. If that doesn't reveal the source of the error, please try to provide a [mcve] and include a portion of the problem input file.

Comment: Labels does seem to be in the file. I tried with MS Excel and Google Sheets. Here's an example of what a relevant csv could look like:
First,Labels
abc,word
xyz,more words
,word

Comment: @LearningSharing are you familiar with Pandas and dataframes? It's a good alternative to native Python

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're reading in the file name and not the file object; therefore, it couldn't find the word key "Labels".

```
with open(file) as csvFile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
```

Try replacing **file** with **csvFile** instead.

```
with open(file) as csvFile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
```

If you printed out the variable reader, you'll have a better understanding.